# One of my apple seedlings is wilting, how can I rescue it?

Tags: apples

Okay, so once, I was eating an apple, and all the seeds inside it had sprouted. So naturally, I planted them in two pots, and they all have been just exploding with growth ever since.

However, today, something happened to one of them. I found out it was raining, so I ran out to bring them back inside. One of them has not been buried deeply enough in the soil, I guess, and it was uprooted when I went out there, and wilty. I'm not sure what happened, except that perhaps the soil dried enough for it to be knocked over by a raindrop? The soil didn't seem dry enough for that to happen, though.

At any rate, I replanted it with the stem deeper in the soil and placed the plants under my plant light inside. What's the best thing I can do for the wilted plant to help it survive? Why did it wilt? It's always done fine out in the sun, as have all the others. Was it just because it was uprooted?

(I do not know how long it was uprooted for. So far I don't think it looks any better, it happened a couple hours ago.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should just wait.

The plant should build again the roots (the microscopic part, which absorb stuffs, and attach them to soil).

Apples have a lot of seeds, so I would not make much efforts. Just try again with new seeds, if this time it will fail.  And usually never assume that 100% of seeds will become an adult plant.

Note: the variety of apple will be different of the original apple: apple are not auto-fertile. This means that, in order to produce apples, apple tree requires pollen of a different variety (and often not a related variety).  Note: this means also that if you want many apples, you should also try to seed different varieties.